# Image button in Help does not match button in editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, help-center

On the [Help page for post formatting on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), there is an image illustrating what the "image" button looks like in the editor.

> [image: image button from the Help page]

However, this doesn't match the button that's in the current iteration of the post editor:

> [image]

To reduce user confusion, they should match.

Ideally, they should match on *all* sites.

Comment: Problem is that on some sites (e.g. [arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/)) it's still that old icon, and I think the help center can't have dynamic contents. So real fix for this might be lot harder than we think.

Comment: @shadow we'd be talking about changing an icon 200 times. Doable.

Comment: @Dan saw it, got nothing to add... "doable" in this case means SE developer will have to go and manually change something hundreds of times. I don't want to be that dev, and it's waste of time. Real solution is making it dynamic, and like I said, this might be complex to do. Anyway, only SE team can really decide, and based on what I've seen here in the years I'm around, neither is likely to happen.

Comment: Got it. I must say though, I'm surprised such a team of programmers cannot make a program that will do it for them. @Shadow

Comment: Well, the question now does not match the answer, as it was only fixed here in MSE. On dozens of other sites, it's still wrong and I doubt anyone will go over them one by one to fix the icon, not to mention new sites. In the very least unaccept the answer. I also flagged the question asking to remove the wrong and misleading [tag:status-completed] tag.

Comment: @Shadow: Okay, I restored your changes. Ideally all the sites would be the same.

Comment: Thanks, thought you insisted on keeping the original, which is your right after all. (but like I said, isn't feasible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, these general help articles *are* actually shared rather than copied to every individual site. I mean, come on. ;)

I updated the image. The alignment is a bit off, but I'm relatively ok with that since it makes the image stand out a bit more, which I appreciate in that particular sentence.

Comment: It's great to see highly responsive updates can and are being done.

Comment: My point [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279876/image-button-in-help-does-not-match-button-in-editor#comment907346_279876), was that you need to do it on a per-site basis. e.g. it's still wrong [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). (so this isn't a real fix, network wide.)

Comment: @Shadow Some of the code-related sites have overrides to add the code formatting specific help into it. I'm not sure why we did that, or why that info can't just be in the network-wide default and sites that don't use code formatting can just ignore it (especially since the code formatting option still appears in their toolbar regardless). Will look into it.