# Inconsistency with the Images section in formatting help page

Tags: bug, images, help-center, help

There is some inconsistency with **Images** section in the formatting help page over Stack Exchange sites.

1. In [Stack Overflow help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), there is an old image icon is displaying

   > [image: SO] in the Images section.

   in [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and other Stack Exchange site contains the new image icon in the Images section.

   > [image: MSE]
2. In some of the Stack Exchange sites like [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/formatting), there I can't see the **Images** section in the formatting help page.

Can these be corrected in the help page?

Comment: [Related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280158) this is still true at the time of this comment.